# Inconsistent display for indexed data with elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

After I update metadata for an indexed item, I'm seeing inconsistent behavior in my search results.

When the search query is "null" the updated metadata is not reflected, but if I use a search term, the updated metadata appears as it should.

I assumed that the issue was related to elasticsearch's caching, but I refreshed the cache and there was no improvement. ([Here's my original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413881/elasticsearch-clear-cache-for-individual-query-term))

What else might be causing the discrepency?

Comment: Your question is rather lacking details. It would greatly help if you would provide an sample of your data and the search you are trying to run. In the meantime, you might want to look at this, it may be related to your question - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was using the Tire gem (which is now "Retired") with Heroku Bonsai Elasticsearch which is updated automatically. The solution was to migrate Tire to the Elasticsearch-Rails gem https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.